# Access a variable value from dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript. I have a global variable like:

```
var contentlabel = {
'post':'Posted Blogpost',
'like':'Liked your Blogpost'
};
```

I want to access the value of contentlable.post dynamically in another function dynamically based on the value retrieved (like, post, ..) as below:

```
var CONTENT_TYPE=content[i].contentType;
alert(CONTENT_TYPE);   //line 1  --> proper output
alert(contentlabel.CONTENT_TYPE);  //line 2  --> undefined
alert(contentlable.post);  //line 3  --> proper output
```

Where content is an array consisting of 'post' and 'like'. 
At line 1 I am getting proper output say: post or like 
In place of 'post' I want to display 'Posted a Blog', so I tried like contentlabel.CONTENT_TYPE, but its not replacing CONTENT_TYPE with either post or like.

Can anyone suggest a way to bind this dynamically.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HWRwt/

Answer (score 5):

You should use square bracket notation: `contentlabel[CONTENT_TYPE]`.

**MORE:** http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html

Comment: @bfavaretto lmao `:)`